# Where are the error messages for Devise located?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to change the message "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing." but I am having trouble finding the file that has this message.

I've looked through all the view files relating to Devise but could not find the message so was wondering where it could be...

Comment: its located under `config\locales\devise.en.yml`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to modify config/locales/devise.en.yml but you must add the settings, they are not there by default.

```
en:
  devise:
    failure:
      unauthenticated: "change this -> You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
```

for other custom error message for devise you can find https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml